# Bootstrapped Firefox extension: how to capture navigation events before a page request?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm building a [bootstrapped Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions) using the [Mozilla add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/) (**not** a traditional XUL addon like other similar questions).

I'd like to capture navigation events *before* they issue HTTP requests.

I've been using `pageMod.PageMod({contentScriptWhen: "start", onAttach: MY_CODE_HERE})` - however, it only triggers onAttach *after* the page is loaded.

That is reinforced by the SDK documentation:

> > contentScriptWhen = "start": load content scripts immediately *after* the document element is inserted into the DOM, but before the DOM content itself has been loaded

On a bootstrapped Firefox extension, is it possible to capture navigation events **before** the page loads?

Comment: How do you define a "navigation event"?

Comment: Navigating to a new page in a top-level window, either by clicking a link or bookmark, or by entering an address in the address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intercept, and handle, requests via the SDK's system events: [How to handle every request in a FF extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112785/how-to-handle-every-request-in-a-firefox-extension/18114793#18114793)

You don't need a pagemod, as this is on the Firefox level, not the per-tab level like the pagemod.

Comment: This won't catch navigation events that don't result to HTTP requests (i.e. pages accessed through the [BFCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_BFCache))

Comment: Right; you asked for HTTP requests before they happened -- bfcache occurs locally outside of the network. If you want to intercept bfcache events, can use the `tabs` modules 'pageshow' event to see if it was pulled from cache or not. [pageshow event](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#pageshow)